# Prevent Browser Malware Ads through HTML code

Tags: malware

I have administrated a community site for quite a while and over the time a handful people have told me that their browsers got infected with a "malware addon" that randomly inserts ad banners in websites they visit.

While they say some websites don't seem to "allow" such foreign insertions, my forum did "allow" the adding of the browser ads. *(For example a malware thing called "OnlineBrowserAdvertising")*

Is there a way (through HTML, Javascript...) to prohibit browsers to add something to my site? I am 100% sure that my site or my webspace are not infected. It's the visitors' browser add-ons messing with my page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot prevent browsers from injecting their own code on your end - the data is retrieved from your server and stored locally (at least temporarily) by the user's device. From the moment the data leaves your server, it is essentially out of your control.

This is purely a client-side issue that can be rectified by following standard security practices. Tell your users to keep their software up-to-date, use an antivirus/firewall solution, and not to visit or download from suspicious websites.

Comment: Thank you for this insightful answer!